Deployment: Procfile with Django Project Structure for more than one App
I need to know how you normally solve this issue.
When you start a project, django creates a folder for the project and a second one inside it with the exact same name and the files like: settings.py, init.py, wsgi.py,  etc.
After Im done with the repo I delete one of the two folders with the same name in order to let Procfile find project.settings inside the wsgi.py.
I want to be able to run the Procfile considering the original structure, because I want to learn how to create more than one app inside a project.
My exact question is. How should I setup my procfile?
right now is like this:
web: gunicorn expenses.wsgi --log-file -
But Then Procfile doesn't find expenses.wsgi
This is my structure:
v expenses
  v expenses
    > static
    __init.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  > finances
  manage.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt

I tried changing the Procfile from    gunicorn expenses.wsgi    to    gunicorn expenses.expenses.wsgi    but then I will tell my to change    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'expenses.settings')    inside the wsgi.py
I tried changing the wsgi.py from os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'expenses.settings') to os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'expenses.expenses.settings') but then it will tell me that it couldn't find the module finances.

I solved it by modifying Procfile like this:
web: gunicorn --chdir expenses expenses.wsgi --log-file -

